# php login with cookies and sessions

Tags: php, cookies, authentication, session-cookies

I want to get a simple login form, for signed users it must say "Hello, login", but cookies are not working and it's always like I'm not signed in. Please help what am I doing wrong?
this is my html file:

```
<form action="index.php" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="login"/>
    <input type="password" name="password"/>
    <input type="submit" value="LOGIN"/>
</form>
```

and php:

```
 <?php
        session_start(); 
        $login = $_POST['login'];
        $password = $_POST['password'];

        function getUsers()
        {
            return array('test'=>'123','jack'=>'345');
        }

        function checkLoginPassword($login, $password)
        {
            $users=getUsers();
            if(!isset($users[$login]))
                return false;
            if($users[$login] != $password)
                return false;
            return true;
        }

        function login($login,$password)
        {
            if(!checkLoginPassword($login,$password)) {
                return false;
            }
            $id = rand(1,100);
            setcookie('user_session',$id,time()+86400);
            $_SESSION['user_'.$id]=$login;
        }

        function isLoggedIn()
        {
            if(!isset($_COOKIE['user_session']))
                return false;
            $id=(int)$_COOKIE['user_session'];
            if(!isset($_SESSION['user_'.$id]))
                return false;
            return true;
        }

        if (isLoggedIn()){
            echo "Hello, ".$login; 
        }
        else echo "You are not signed in!";
```

Comment: Why are you using regular cookies AND sessions?

Comment: logging in a user, setting a uuid to the user saving it to server and sending it as a cookie to the user, then tracking the details of the user with sessions is a common solution. (i.e. when the user is back, sessions will be expired but the uuid in the cookies can be used to verify the user and re-initiate the session). the usage here is -wrong-, but cookies+session is a commonly done, good solution to this problem. cookies and sessions -do not- share the same purpose. rather, they complement each other in scenarios like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function isLoggedIn()
{
    if(!isset($_COOKIE['user_session']))
        return false;
    $id=(int)$_COOKIE['user_session'];
    if(!isset($_SESSION['user_'.$id]))
        return false;
    return true;
}
```

this solution is bad, but to actually answer your question, the issue is $id is not set here. there is no local, nor global $id

Answer (score 0):

Even when you press login in html in php is this function not mentioned at all.

You need to put this in your code and than it will work.

```
if (!empty($_POST)) {
    $login = $_POST['login'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];

    login($login, $password);
}
```